# translate kotlin set value into java

Tags: java, kotlin

I cannot understand the meaning of the code. Can you give me a help to translate the code into Java?

```
private var framePeriodMs: Long = 0

var frameRate: Float = Float.MAX_VALUE
    set(value) {
        this.framePeriodMs = (1000 / value).toLong()
        log.info("framePeriodMs: $framePeriodMs")
        field = value
    }
```

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 3):

This should be about right (though my Java's rusty):

```java
private long framePeriodMs = 0;

private float frameRate = Float.MAX_VALUE;

public float getFrameRate() {
    return frameRate;
}

public void setFrameRate(float newFrameRate) {
    this.framePeriodMs = (long)(1000 / newFrameRate);
    log.info("framePeriodMs: " + framePeriodMs);
    this.frameRate = newFrameRate;
}
```

The `value` coming into the `set(...) { ... }` function is just like a parameter into a Java setter.